Minimize $||A-AWW^TA^T||_F$ w.r.t. $W$
Given $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $A \in \{0,1\}^{n \times n}$, we aim to find
$$\arg \min_{W \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}} f(W) = ||A-AWW^TA^T||_F,$$
where $||\cdot||_F$ represents the Frobenius norm with
$$||X||_F = \sqrt{\sum_{i,j} {X^2_{ij}}}.$$

What I have tried
Taking the derivative, we have
$$\frac{\partial f^2(W)}{\partial W} = A^T (A + A^T - 2AWW^TA^T) AW$$ and we need
$$A^T (A + A^T - 2AWW^TA^T) AW = 0.$$
$W = 0$ satisfies it but it is in general not the optimum.

What norm is $\lVert M \rVert_2$? Usually it denotes the largest eigenvalue of $M$.

@TedBlack No. It usually denotes the largest singular value of $M$.

@user1551 you are right; square root or eigenvalue, the derivative that is calculated above does not look right.

I am sorry for the confusion. I meant to write Frobenius norm, which should be $||\cdot||{2,2}$ or $||\cdot||{F}$. Let me correct it.

Denote by $H$ and $K$ the symmetric and skew-symmetric parts of $A$ respectively. Let $A=U\Sigma V^T$ be a singular value decomposition. Then
\begin{align*}
\|A-AWW^TA^T\|_F^2
&=\|H-AWW^TA^T\|_F^2+\|K\|_F^2\\
&= \|H'-\Sigma P\Sigma\|_F^2+\|K\|_F^2\\
\end{align*}
where $H'=U^THU$ and $P=V^TWW^TV$.
Let $r$ be the rank of $A$. Then $\Sigma=S\oplus0$ for some $r\times r$ positive diagonal matrix $S$. Let $H_1$ and $P_1$ be the leading principal $r\times r$ matrices of $H'$ and $P$ respectively. Then $\|H'-\Sigma P\Sigma\|_F^2=\|H_1-SP_1S\|_F^2+\text{constant}$. If $H_1=QDQ^T$ is an orthogonal diagonalisation, then the unique global minimiser of $\|H_1-SP_1S\|_F$ is given by $P_1=S^{-1}Q\max(D,0)Q^TS^{-1}$, where $\max(D,0)$ is the entrywise maximum of $D$ and the zero matrix. It follows that the global minimisers to the original minimisation problem are given by those matrices $W$ such that $WW^T$ is in the form of
$$
V\pmatrix{P_1&\ast\\ \ast&\ast}V^T.
$$
In particular, one may take
$$
W=V\pmatrix{L&0\\ 0&0}
$$
when $L$ is either $P_1^{1/2}$ or the Cholesky factor of $P_1$.

Thanks a lot! But as I can see, here $P$ (and thus $P_1$) is defined by $W$, and $W$ is defined by $L$ (and thus $P_1$). How should I find $W$ in such a case?
